# working with python cdll windows dll got an memory exception

Tags: python, delphi

I receive this error when I try to call this function written in Delphi. But another code works fine. Maybe I'm not declaring the args ans result types? I am using 32Bit python 3.7). Related code snippets:

Delphi:

```
Test(deposit, MarginCall: double; CallBack: TProgrCallBackProc); stdcall;
```

Python:

```py
self.FTCore = ctypes.WinDLL(self.FTCore_library_path)
self.FTCore.Test.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]
self.FTCore.Test.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)
deposit = ctypes.c_double(100)
callback = ctypes.c_double(1)
self.FTCore.Test(deposit, callback)
```

Error:

```
violation reading 0x00000004
```

Comment: Delphi is Delphi, a variant of Pascal. The first snippet you show is a Delphi snippet, not C.

Comment: You have a mismatch in number of arguments. In Delphi code there are `deposit` and `MarginCall` doubles and `CallBack`. In the Python call you pass only `deposit` and `CallBack` arguments.

Comment: @TomBrunberg  yep, i see third argument - is func, how to declare this argument like a func type?

Comment: A callback function is just a function, that is reachable from the outside. For this you pass the address of that function to the external module.  For further reading look at this example https://www.localsolver.com/docs/last/advancedfeatures/callbacks.html

Comment: @Sherlock70 The issue is more about the ctypes mechanism for declaring the callback parameter list and types.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Typical for me to miss that... Thanks. The link is worth looking at anyways...I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three errors that I can see:

1. The Delphi function accepts three arguments, you define only two in `argtypes`. You will need to define the third argument, `TProgrCallBackProc` defined somewhere in the Delphi code.
2. The two double parameters are passed by value, but you define them as pointers to double in your `argtypes` definition. They should be defined as plain `ctypes.c_double`.
3. The Delphi function has no return value, but your `restype` contradicts that. You need to set `restype` to `None`.